# Get data by applying conditions within a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to get two set of data. Here is how data looks like after order it by desc

```
Select RecordId,Tab, Status, CreatedDate 
from Table1
Order By Tab, CreatedDate Desc
```

| RecordId | Tab | Status | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 2021-10-13 08:15:02.154 |
| 1 | 100 | 2 | 2021-10-13 08:04:05.456 |
| 2 | 200 | 2 | 2021-10-13 08:13:00.198 |
| 2 | 200 | 1 | 2021-10-13 08:07:09.052 |
| 2 | 200 | 3 | 2021-10-13 08:04:03.306 |
| 3 | 300 | 1 | 2021-10-13 08:12:02.051 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 | 2021-10-13 08:08:05.158 |
| 3 | 300 | 3 | 2021-10-13 08:02:01.756 |
| 4 | 400 | 3 | 2021-10-13 08:14:01.356 |
| 4 | 400 | 1 | 2021-10-13 08:09:05.753 |
| 4 | 400 | 2 | 2021-10-13 08:05:06.152 |

First Set : Only those RecordId, which has current Status as 1 (In our case RecordId 1 and 3)

Second Set : Only those RecordId, Where it has status as 1 earlier but got changed currently (In our case RecordId 2 and 4)

Please help me in writing a query on this.

Comment: This seems like homework; it is a trivial problem.  If so, you will do better for your own loearning to research this for yourself.  Each problem is solved by adding a simple WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is what you are looking for:

```
Select RecordId as FirstSet
from Table1 t1
where t1.Status = 1 and not exists (
    select * from Table1 t2 where t2.RecordId = t1.RecordId and t2.CreatedDate > t1.CreatedDate
)

Select RecordId as SecondSet
from Table1 t1
where t1.Status = 1 and exists (
    select * from Table1 t2 where t2.RecordId = t1.RecordId and t2.CreatedDate > t1.CreatedDate
)
```

Comment: Thank you Carlos for your quick help. This is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row-numbering and a windowed count for these queries

```
SELECT
  RecordId,
  Tab,
  Status,
  CreatedDate 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
    FROM Table1
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND Status = 1
ORDER BY Tab, CreatedDate Desc;

SELECT
  RecordId,
  Tab,
  Status,
  CreatedDate 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC),
      has1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY RecordId)
    FROM Table1
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND Status <> 1 AND has1 = 1
ORDER BY Tab, CreatedDate Desc;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d263548a88c484022e6f364d963ff50)